# Image validation doesn't work on multiple accept input using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate multiple accept imput image extension inside bootstrap pop. I'm using button type button `type="button"` because `submit` is closing the pop. I'm trying to validate the form using function.

### Code

```
<form id="promotionImageForm_<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>"  autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Add More Images</label>
    <input type="file"  name="pm_image[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="pmMultiImgs_<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>" />
    <button type="button" onclick="return multiUpload(<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>);" id="pmMultibTn" />Add</button>
</form>

//JS
    function multiUpload(pmID){
        $('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID).validate({ 
            rules: {
            },
            messages: {
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert('Form Submitted');
            }
        });
        /*Multi Images */
        $('#pmMultiImgs_'+pmID).each(function() {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png",
                messages: {
                    accept: "Only jpeg, jpg or png images"
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

But above function is showing nothing, can anyone guide me where i'm wrong and how can i fix it. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: In its present form your code cannot be turned into a working demo.  Please remove the PHP and construct a self-contained demo that shows us the actual problem as it happens.  Otherwise, the validation portion of your code is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/cap6b8m1/

Comment: Your `button` markup is also invalid.  You cannot have a self-closing `<button />` tag along with a closing `</button>` tag.  The `button` element is a container, so it can only be `<button>...</button>`.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for sharing knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The validation portion of your code is working:  [jsfiddle.net/cap6b8m1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cap6b8m1/)

However, please note that the `.validate()` method is used for initializing the plugin on your form.  So based on the code contained within your `multiUpload()` function, nothing will be initialized until ***after*** the "Add" button is clicked.

Simply remove the `.validate()` and `.rules()` methods from the `multiUpload()` function so these can intialize immediately, and change the "Add" button into a `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit" id="pmMultibTn">Add</button>
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/qktztesu/](http://jsfiddle.net/qktztesu/)**

Otherwise, please remove the PHP and construct a self-contained demo that shows us the actual problem as it happens.